# TypeError: Cannot read property "-1" of undefined in Google Sheets Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I've been trying to get this script working again, to no avail. It persistently throws a 'TypeError: Cannot read property "-1" from undefined. (line 10, file "Code")' and I can't figure out why it's breaking.

```
function attackPower(level,basePower) 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rng=sht.getRange('aw3:bf35');
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    var bpwrrng=sht.getRange('aw3:aw35');
    var bpwrrngA=bpwrrng.getValues();
    var bpwridx=bpwrrngA[0].indexOf(basePower);
    var r=rngA[level][bpwridx];
    return r;
}
```

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QBJVS7xyFBNLfxHXn75HH1V9UUh-TNeQIj6XsFM3Ao4/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet that this script applies to.

Comment: Values of "level" and "basePower" are required for understanding the error.

Comment: Use Logger.log() to debug the values you are getting. This probably is a case of 'index out of range' in arrays. Remember that sheets are two dimensional.